# Group every nth line command output in a CSV format

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

Am looking for a way to parse a multi line command output; group every multiple of `nth` line and format in CSV format.

```
$ cat file
ABC
123
62p4-123
DEF
456
62p4-456
```

I need the o/p grouped at every `3rd` line, and at multiples of 3, i.e 3rd, 6th and 9th followed by 1st,4th and 7th and 2nd, 5th and 8th respectively in comma separated format

```
ABC,DEF
123,456
62p4-123,62p4-456
```

This is just a sample format and my actual use case is a `json` o/p that I want to format using tools/utilities in `bash` and I don't need a formatting option within `jq` I used for parsing the data.

I found several ways in `awk` like `awk 'NR % 3 == 0'` but I cannot make this repeat for other lines.

EDIT:- Am updating my actual JSON o/p returned from `jq` here to get the most effective solution

```
4496
http://xxx/yyy
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1
4497
http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1
4498
http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/otherfile.c
```

Expected o/p

```
4496,4497,4498
http://xxx/yyy,http://xxx/yyy/zzz,http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,home/build/branches/mmm/otherfile.c
```

Comment: What output do you expect with more lines? (please show an input with 9 or 12 lines).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Updated!

Comment: I see. I'm not sure this is to be tolerated on SO, though, as we clearly have duplicates! `:)`.

Comment: Ok will it make sense if I paste the answer as a comment, and delete this post?

Comment: Well, now the situation is weird: your question is good (well-posed, etc.), and the other one is not as good (yet, salvageable through mild edits). I have no idea what to do… wait and see `:D`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simpler way

```
$ pr -2ts, file

ABC,DEF
123,456
62p4-123,62p4-456
```

for the other input change the number of columns to 3.

```
$ pr -3ts, file

4496,4497,4498
http://xxx/yyy,http://xxx/yyy/zzz,http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/otherfile.c
```

If you only know the number of lines, not the final number of columns you can do this

```
$ pr -$(awk 'END{print NR/3}' file) -ts, file
```

Comment: `pr` looks really simple! Thanks. But unfortunately can't use it since it doesn't come as part of `GNU coreutils`

Comment: @Inian: [of course it does](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/pr-invocation.html#pr-invocation).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Didn't test it on my Mac, installed GNU coreutils separately, since the `pr --version` didn't mention it being part of the coreutils, didn't bother to attempt with it. Actually it works cool with my native FreeBSD version

Comment: Note that you need to know the number of lines in advance to give the number of columns to `pr`. This means that the file has to be read twice.

Comment: Am going to accept this answer considering the portability and the simplicity of this to use. Thanks @karakfa

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for the note! Will remember it though!

Comment: @karakfa the pr+awk solution you added will fail with cryptic error messages given an empty input file or an input file that has a number of lines that's not evenly divisible by the number of output columns you want. You'd need something like `pr -$(awk 'END{print (NR ? int((NR+2)/3) : 1)}' file) -ts, file` to solve both problems but I'm not sure even that does it.

Comment: Yes there is no validation, assumes the file has data integrity.  Also needs to scan the file twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v OFS=, 'NR<4{a[NR]=$0; next} {i=(NR%3?NR%3:3); a[i] = a[i] OFS $0} 
          END{for(i=1; i<=3; i++) print a[i]}' file

4496,4497,4498
http://xxx/yyy,http://xxx/yyy/zzz,http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/otherfile.c
```

Comment: After 3rd line, this awk is printing `line-3,line`, check edited answer for the output I am getting with your edited question.

Comment: This works and I get how it works! :) Buying some time for a simpler solution if possible

Comment: I really have to accept this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39574272/5291015, answering considering its simplicity and portability. If only I can accept more than one answer :)

Comment: @Inian that answer is only simple because it doesn't solve the problem. It's also less portable than any of the awk answers you got since it requires GNU tools while the awk solutions will work as-is in any UNIX installation and it's less efficient since it has to read the input file twice once you add the rest of the solution and it's less robust as it will fail cryptically given some input file contents.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, I couldn't have summed it up better. Reading a file twice and falling it apart when lines are multiples of 3 is a big let down with `pr` based solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
4496
http://xxx/yyy
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1
4497
http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1
4498
http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/otherfile.c

$ perl -lne '$i = ($.-1)%3; $f[$i] .= $f[$i] ? ",$_" : $_; END{print foreach (@f)}' ip.txt 
4496,4497,4498
http://xxx/yyy,http://xxx/yyy/zzz,http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/otherfile.c
```

Here's an alternate solution, inefficient in terms of performance though

```
$ (sed -n '1~3p' ip.txt ; sed -n '2~3p' ip.txt ; sed -n '3~3p' ip.txt) | pr -ats, -$(echo $(wc -l < ip.txt)/3 | bc)
4496,4497,4498
http://xxx/yyy,http://xxx/yyy/zzz,http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/otherfile.c
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But I `prefer` a solution using other bash tools like `awk`. If nothing else works, I will accept this answer!

Comment: @Inian, ok.. am more comfortable with `perl` and dunno how to code same logic in `awk`.. would a hacky but readable solution with GNU `sed`, `pr` and `bc` work for you?

Comment: As long as the tools are part of `GNU coreutils`.

Answer (score 1):

A pedestrian, pure Bash (≥4) approach, reading the whole file in memory with `mapfile`.

```
#!/bin/bash

n=3

mapfile -t ary < file

for ((i=0;i<n;++i)); do
    for ((j=i;j<${#ary[@]};j+=n)); do
        (( j >= n )) && printf ,
        printf '%s' "${ary[j]}"
    done
    echo
done
```

This is not exactly very efficient (so don't use it for very large files).

---

A variation is to build up the lines to be output while the file is read.

```
#!/bin/bash

n=3
ary=()
linenb=0

while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((linenb>=n)) && ary[linenb%n]+=,
    ary[linenb++%n]+=$line
done < file

printf '%s\n' "${ary[@]}"
```

Again, this is not very efficient for very large files (but it's pure Bash!).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{k=((NR-1)%3)+1} {a[k]=(k in a ? a[k] "," : "") $0} END{for (i=1;i<=3;i++) print a[i]}' file
ABC,DEF
123,456
62p4-123,62p4-456

$ awk '{k=((NR-1)%3)+1} {a[k]=(k in a ? a[k] "," : "") $0} END{for (i=1;i<=3;i++) print a[i]}' file
4496,4497,4498
http://xxx/yyy,http://xxx/yyy/zzz,http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/file1,/home/build/branches/mmm/otherfile.c
```

Comment: An `awk` solution without Ed's answer? :) no way! answer looks the same logic as in anubhava's answer below. To be honest, I was looking forward to a even more simpler solution than this from you :)

Comment: This is as simple as it gets. The difference between this and @anubhava's answer is mine has the idiomatic way of creating and then using an index from 1 to n (i.e. `k=((NR-1)%n)+1)`) and so only needs to test the end of the range once instead of 4 times when populating the array.